# Android Studio 3 add library to java library module

Tags: java, android, gradle

I used to have in my android project an extra java library module used to run quick java only tests. This module had some java libraries added in its build.gradle and a custom run configuration.
When I upgraded to AS 3 and Gradle 3 this module started giving me the following error when creating a new object of any library :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/DateTime
at com.example.javatest.Test.main(Test.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.DateTime
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

The crash happens only when I create an object of a library. This doesn't crash :

```
Datetime datetime;
Period period;
```

This does :

```
Datetime datetime = new Datetime();
Period period = new Period();
```

I tried creating the module again with the AS wizard but no luck. Also tried creating the run config again. When using only pure java code it doesn't crash.

I tried adding the library with `implementation xxx` and also as a jar but same result.

The build.gradle for the module :

```
apply plugin: 'java'


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //Tried both, not at the same time
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
    implementation files('libs/joda-time-2.9.9.jar')

    implementation 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.6'
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: take a look at [api vs. implementation](https://blog.mindorks.com/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa)